# Does $\|z\|=(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ define a norm on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Does  $\| z\|=(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|})^{\frac{1}{2}}$, with $z=(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, define a norm on $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: What did you try so far? do you know the definition of a norm?

Comment: yes.Is exist a easy criterion for checking Triangle inequality؟

Comment: you should check the positive homogeneity first

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but if you know the definition of a norm then you know you need to check a few properties. Did you check those for the proposed norm you give in the question?

Comment: Positive homogeneity is true.My problem is with Triangle inequality

Comment: The LHS of the title must be $\left\|z\right\|$?

Answer (score 4):

Try positive homogenity

$\|e_1\|=1$ and 
$$\left\|\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right\|= \sqrt{\sqrt{2}}\neq 2$$